# Querying dynamic in asp.NET with SQL server

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic-linq

(If the title isn't representative for this question please say so, I couldn't come up with a good short description)

I'm trying to implement an advanced search function for my web application. This search has to be able to search on a lot of possible combinations. 
[image]

Like shown in the picture every group (AND or OR) can have another group or conditions that can be equal or not equal. The picture should result in a where clause that look like this:

```
WHERE (Application like '%User%' AND Host not like '%fjzhykjety%') OR (REMOTE_HOST like '%uykirlyy%' AND REMOTE_PORT not like '%55555%')
```

Application, Host and REMOTE_HOST are strings, REMOTE_PORT is a nullable int. I also have a GUID that has to be searchable.

At the moment this frontend search is written in angular and gives me following json (the json depends on the nested groups and conditions) for the example:

```
{
    "group": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "rules": [
            {
                "group": {
                    "operator": "AND",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "condition": "=",
                            "field": {
                                "name": "Application",
                                "type": "select"
                            },
                            "data": "User"
                        },
                        {
                            "condition": "<>",
                            "field": {
                                "name": "Host",
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "data": "fjzhykjety"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "group": {
                    "operator": "AND",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "condition": "=",
                            "field": {
                                "name": "REMOTE_HOST",
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "data": "uykirlyy"
                        },
                        {
                            "condition": "<>",
                            "field": {
                                "name": "REMOTE_PORT",
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "data": 55555
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need a way to sent this data to my .NET application (using a REST API) and query it in the database. I looked into dynamic linq for making the query but because the format of the json file isn't always the same it's hard to make a class in C# for it and build a dynamic linq query for this search.

What is the best way to implement this advanced search?

Comment: Did you end this functionality? I'm currently working in a very similar feature, the main difference is that I have to include joins and the fields are "unknown" provided dynamically based on the fields selection from the previous join. At the end my app user want a "view modeler" like the SQL Managment.  I'm using SqlKata and I thinks that is a little more simply and flexible about your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for dynamic query. Also you can combine with your query linqkit is good predicate builder.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx
https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

```
public List<CustomerPointsDetail> GetCustomerPointsDetails(
            int customerId,
            int? catalogRewardId = null,
            long? couponId = null,
            long? transactionId = null,
            CustomerPointsDetailStatus? inStatus = null,
            CustomerPointsDetailStatus? notInStatus = null,
            bool? isPointsGreaterThanZero = null,
            bool? isRemainingPointsGreaterThanZero = null,
            CustomerPointsDetailOperationType? operationType = null,
            DateTime? startDate = null,
            DateTime? endDate = null,
            bool isExpiredRecordsIncluded = false)
        {
            var query = this.customerPointsDetailRepository.Table.Where(cpd => cpd.CustomerId == customerId);

            if (catalogRewardId.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.CatalogRewardId == catalogRewardId);
            }

            if (couponId.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.CouponId == couponId);
            }

            if (transactionId.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.TransactionId == transactionId);
            }

            if (inStatus.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.Status == inStatus);
            }

            if (notInStatus.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.Status != notInStatus);
            }

            if (isRemainingPointsGreaterThanZero.HasValue)
            {
                if (isRemainingPointsGreaterThanZero.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.RemainingPoints.HasValue && cpd.RemainingPoints > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.RemainingPoints.HasValue && cpd.RemainingPoints < 0);
                }
            }

            if (isPointsGreaterThanZero.HasValue)
            {
                if (isPointsGreaterThanZero.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.Points > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.Points < 0);
                }
            }

            if (operationType.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.OperationType == operationType);
            }

            if (!isExpiredRecordsIncluded)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => !cpd.PointsExpireDate.HasValue
                                           || (cpd.PointsExpireDate.HasValue && cpd.PointsExpireDate > DateTime.Now));
            }

            if (startDate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.CreateDate >= startDate);
            }

            if (endDate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(cpd => cpd.CreateDate <= endDate);
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(cpd => cpd.PointsExpireDate);

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Linqkit sample here

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }

  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

---

Edit

You need to an expression give your method and . You can combine with Linqkit.

```
    Expression<Func<Product, bool>> e1 = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Product, bool>("Type= \"Type_A\"");    

    OR 

Expression<Func<Product, bool>> e1 =  p => p.Type="Type_A";
```

Before call you SearchProduct in Program

```
var expressions = new Dictionary<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>, bool>();

Expression<Func<Product, bool>> e1 =  p => p.Type="Type_A";
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> e2 =  p => p.Type="Type_B";

expressions.Add(e1,true);
expressions.Add(e2,true);

SearchProducts(expressions); //send expression list for evoluate

    IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (Dictionary<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>, bool>  expressionList)
    {
      var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

      foreach(expression in expressionList)
      {

           if(expression.Value) // AND
           {
               predicate = predicate.And(expression.Key);
           }else   // OR
           {
               predicate = predicate.Or(expression.Key);
           }

       }
       .
       .
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, linqkit looks promising for the AND and OR clauses. However the dynamic query must have the possibility to check the same property more than once. Like in the following example:
![Same Property](http://i.imgur.com/eEbjIL8.png)

Comment: Had more than one condition queries , build with AND or OR clause. Linqkit  give you short way for this. You can give N time same property with last method